# kivy slider event trigger

Tags: python, kivy

I need a slider to output an integer value that I can use for something. I need this event to trigger only when the slider is moved by click, and to do nothing when the slider value is changed programatically.

Here is my code: (stripped to neccesary code)

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

def CheckSong(threadName, songName, albumCover, artistName, timeBar):
            
            # this try/except is in a loop i just deleted it to shorten the code displayed here
            try:
                timeBar.value = sp.current_playback()['progress_ms']
                
            except:
                None

            time.sleep(1)


timeBar = Slider(min=0, max=100, value=0)
timeBar.value_track=True
timeBar.value_track_color=[1, 0, 0, 1]
timeBar.pos=(45,-40)
timeBar.size_hint=(.8,1)
timeBar.cursor_size=(0,0)

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    released = super(timeBar, self).on_touch_up(touch)
    if released:
        timeChange()
    return released

################################################################

class SpotipyWidget(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout(size = (WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT))   # Create layout

        layout.add_widget(timeBar)

        return layout
    

#####################################################################

songThread = threading.Thread(target=CheckSong, args=("songThread", songName, albumCover, artistName, timeBar))    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpotipyWidget().run()       # Run the widget
```

My current issue is when i use `timeBar.bind(value=someFunction())` that function triggers every time the value is changed. I have the value polled with a song that I am playing to create a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a flag to indicate when the value change should or should not be ignored. Something like this:

```
ignore_change = False

def CheckSong(threadName, songName, albumCover, artistName, timeBar):
    global ignore_change
    # this try/except is in a loop i just deleted it to shorten the code displayed here
    while True:
        try:
            ignore_change = True
            timeBar.value += 10

        except:
            None

        time.sleep(1)

def bubba(*args):
    global ignore_change

    if ignore_change:
        ignore_change = False
    else:
        print('not ignoring')

timeBar.bind(value=bubba)
```